# Graph Theory Bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

> If there is a room with 15 women, each woman shakes the hands of 8 men and each man shakes the hands of 6 women, how men there are in the room?

So far I wrote this:
Women group A=$(v_1...,v_m)$ men group B=$(u_1....,u_n)$
$G=(A,B,E) $ , $|A|=m=15 $ ,$|B|=n$
and $N(u_n)=6$,$N(v_n)=8$
is it correct? and i so how can i move on to solve it?

Comment: How many edges are there? How many edges are there per man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $n$ men then $15\times8$ and $n\times 6$ both equal the number of handshakes that involve a man and a woman.

That implies $n=20$.

Comment: well thats what i thought at first... but then i noticed that if women 1 to 6 shake the hand of the same 8 men, and 7 to 12 shake another 8 men, theres are 3 more women that each need to shake 8 men.... ?

Comment: Well, I think that this just excludes that the sketched  scenario  (twice $6$ women shaking hands with $8$ men, and disjoint) will indeed occur.